# Download transfer question

Tags: google-play-music

I downloaded a music album from the Google playstore on my Samsung phone.  How do I transfer that album to my Samsung Music App?

Answer (score 0):

It can be only used in Google Play Music app,unless you make it avaiable offline. Then you will find your music on your phone, and SMA will register it automaticly.